# Reducing Memory FootPrint Of Android App

Tags: android, memory-management

I have been trying to reduce memory usage of the app.

It seems the memory allocation is not an issue as the heap shows allocation of 8mb out of 54mb being used.

Majority of the memory is consumed by **code** and **native** section, which doesnt seem right at all. I dont know how to go about it as allocation is not a problem as it seems.

Any help is most Welcome.

[image]

Comment: give some more info about your app. what it does and are you using bitmaps in your app etc etc.

Comment: This is the snapshot when app is launched, on Splash Screen with Blank screen

Comment: Bitmap, global services , asyncTask and receiver are main memory consuming.

Comment: yes, but kindly note that allocation on heap is only 8mb, We are on splash screen, with loading almost nothing. The code sections is consuming  25mb, which is the problem